# Need something like packages.json for atom packages

Tags: atom-editor

Just started to using Atom. Is there anyway to save install package names into a file (git will keep track of this file). Thus after installing atom into another computer we wouldn't have to install all packages one by one. Is there something like `npm install` for atom to install packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by marking the packages as favorites (or *stars*). You can do this through the Atom web site (http://atom.io/packages). Create an account there, and start *star*'ing packages you like by clicking the *star* icon on the package's overview page. You can also use the `apm star <package_name>` command to do the same from command line.

You can then run `apm stars --install` to install all of your *star*'ed packages locally. It will provide information on how to set your user account when you run it for the first time.

Some other (more advanced) ways of achieving a similar result are listed here: http://www.atomtips.com/how-to-synchronize-atom-between-computers/